# Test generation in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio 2010 had a feature with which it was possible to generate a test method for each public method or property of a class. Even I know that the result was more or less use less, I was wondering if this feature still exists in VS2012 because I didn't find it.

Comment: Damn it, I just found the answer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/03/08/what-s-new-in-visual-studio-11-beta-unit-testing.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature has been removed from VS 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Try this plugin:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2013/06/13/announcing-the-unit-test-generator-visual-studio-extension-beta.aspx

I miss the option to configure the structure in which it creates tests but besides that it works fine.